# Const struct assigned to struct

Tags: visual-c++

I have a simple function:

```
StudentType* SortStudentsByName(const StudentType* student, int numStudents)
{
    StudentType* returnStudent = new (nothrow) StudentType[numStudents];
    returnStudent = student; // error
}
```

it keeps saying `Type const StudentType* cannot be assigned to StudentType*`, which is ridiculous because its the same exact type, one is just a constant.

If i remove the `const` from the function parameter list, it works.

Im not allowed to remove the `const` though, because that array shouldn't be modified.

A couple important things:

(1) Both arrays are constructed at runtime to the same size, ensured by the other parameter.

(2) bitcopy should handle this, and it handles the non-const version.

Is there any way to make this work, or do i have to do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the same. You are trying to assign **const pointer to a non const pointer**. Another words: trying to assign Mutable pointer to a constant StudentType to a non-const pointer.
It does make sense to change something that is declared const to no-cont, meaning you could change a value of a constant.

What you are trying to do is to copy one object to another using shallow copy. in order to do so, you must copy object to another object not pointer to a pointer. you have to dereference pointers.:

```
*returnStudent = *student
```

Or if structure contains pointer types, shallow copy will not do. You will have to copy each member taking care of copying memory pointers point to, or write copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you, but you really aren't making sense. It turns out this thing was a typo in my code that I had, and you are right about dereferencing being the solution. But pointers just hold memory addresses, and transferring a 32 bit memory address into a pointer shouldn't actually present any problems. But hey, c++ does these things i guess.